# Error getting 3D points from Disparity

Tags: graphics, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

So I calculate the disparity between 2 stereo images(left and right).It looks correct 
(because it is somewhat similar in shape to the original image).After this I use the line :-

```
cvReprojectImageTo3D(&disparity, threeDimage, &Q);
```

and get the answers in threeDimage.It is a matrix and I access it as :-

```
for(int ii=0;ii<threeDimage->rows;ii++)
    {       
    float *data = (float *)(threeDimage->data.ptr + ii * threeDimage->step);

    for(int jj=0;jj<threeDimage->cols*3;jj=jj+3) 
   {


      float a=data[jj];
      float b=data[jj+1];
      float c=data[jj+2];
      fprintf(fpp,"%f %f %f \n", a,b,c);

       }

}
```

But the problem is it doesnt seem to give me a correct answer.I get lot of repeated values in my file.Any hint on what might be going wrong?Is the traversal of the matrix correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get a different 3D distance from points where there is an edge in the disparity map. If you have large areas of the same disparity (flat grey in the input image) then they will have the same Z.

Comment: Well I am trying to reconstruct a face and yes most of the central portion of the image does seem same gray level.But I guess the disparity map is right(I can see outline of the face)? How can I possibly improve it to get a more sensible 3d cloud.I use some of the latest algorithms to generate the disparity map.

Comment: and more so there are different colored patches in the image but its like everything shows up in a line ! which is completely weird and makes me think that there might be something wrong with the reprojection part.